`$SHELL` still points to `/bin/sh` over SSH after `chsh -s $(which fish)`
I am using OpenBSD-current. After doas pkg_add fish, I ran chsh -s $(which fish) to change the default shell of my user qys to fish, and it works:
$ /usr/bin/ssh magicbane
Last login: Wed Aug 21 11:17:12 on ttyp0 from 100.94.151.103
OpenBSD 7.6-beta (GENERIC.MP) #270: Tue Aug 20 10:51:30 MDT 2024

Welcome to OpenBSD: The proactively secure Unix-like operating system.

Please use the sendbug(1) utility to report bugs in the system.
Before reporting a bug, please try to reproduce it with the latest
version of the code.  With bug reports, please try to ensure that
enough information to reproduce the problem is enclosed, and if a
known fix for it exists, include that as well.

You have new mail.
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish
qys@magicbane ~> echo $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/fish

However,
$ /usr/bin/ssh magicbane 'echo $SHELL'
/bin/sh

I wonder why this didn't give me /usr/local/bin/fish? This is not a problem itself, but I suspect it has something to do with this issue that I'm trying to solve.

Are you at all using SSH connection sharing? If not, I can not reproduce this on my OpenBSD system.  If you are using connection sharing, then issue ssh -O exit magicbane to close the master connection.

Isn’t SHELL meant to point to a POSIX-/Bourne-compatible shell (which fish isn’t)?

What does ssh magicbane getent passwd qys output?

@user3840170 SHELL is set to the user's login shell by the login process (from the passwd database). Whether this is a POSIX shell or Python does not matter.

@Kusalananda I'm not sure what is SSH connection sharing. How do I check if I have it enabled? Also /usr/bin/ssh -O exit magicbane gives me No ControlPath specified for "-O" command and exit code 255.

Ok, good, then I don't know what's up.

@muru It gives qys:*:1000:1000:Qingyao Sun:/home/qys:/usr/local/bin/fish, which seems correct.

Does the ssh server config use ForceCommand anywhere?

@Kusalananda Wait a second. I forgot to mention that I'm using Tailscale SSH, and SSHing over the local IP address does give me /usr/local/bin/fish! Maybe Tailscale is doing some connection sharing under the hood? I'm not sure how to check that though.

@muru I don't think so. I'm just using the default /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

"This routes SSH traffic for the device from the Tailscale network to an SSH server run by Tailscale, instead of your standard SSH server." ... so now you need to go see how Tailscale does user shell management
